# How to affect order of targets, add additional steps etc. for Makefile.am?

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

Can I manage Makefile.am as I got used to manage Makefile?

Usually I create targets which calls each other in order to make the project built.

But in Makefile.am I have some mysterious `libqqq_la_SOURCES = ...` which I don't know what is it doing exactly.

Where to write what compiler should it use for the given source? Where to add a step that "qqq.c is generated from qqq.vala"?

How to write Makefile.am as just Makefile?

Comment: Why are you using Automake if you don't know what it's doing and you are comfortable using makefiles directly?  What is your goal?

Comment: Because of I'm editing the project that uses automake. (New version is actually using qmake, so I'll probably just migrate)

Answer (score 3):

Automake in 1.11 does have Vala support.

configure.ac:

```
AM_PROG_VALAC
```

Makefile.am:

```
AM_VALAFLAGS = whateverelse
whatever_SOURCES = xxx.vala
```

Answer (score 0):

Automake will automatically copy over any Make targets you specify in Makefile.am into the generated Makefile. So you can generate any custom, complicated things just by including it in the .am file.

However, you shouldn't do this for *everything* -- that defeats the benefit that Automake is trying to provide you. Specifying

```
bin_PROGRAMS=foo
AM_CFLAGS=$(DEPS_CFLAGS)
foo_SOURCES=file1.cpp file2.cpp
foo_LDADD=$(DEPS_LIBS)
```

will generate a standard Make target anyway. I recommend you learn to use Automake macros for most standard things -- it will be more portable that way.

The best way to learn the rich variety of Autotools features is not to read the manual -- it's way too complicated and unorganizable. My suggestion is simply to take an existing open-source GNU project that is similar in build style (dependencies, platforms, etc) to yours, and examine its Autoconf and Automake files. The established projects have learned quite a few tricks that you can learn from.

Comment: Which one is mixture of Vala, C and C++?

Comment: Automake should automatically figure out C and C++ based on the extensions. It doesn't have first-class support for Vala, but here's a link about adding some basic support for arbitrary languages:  http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/manuals/automake/automake_18.html#SEC83

Comment: If your project really is so "out there" (a combination of three languages, one of which is **very** non-mainstream), then maybe Autotools is not well-suited for your project anyway. How portable is Vala?

Comment: AM_CPPFLAGS is for preprocessor flags, you should use AM_CFLAGS for CFLAGS.

Comment: Note: -D and -I (-DFOO -Iinclude/) are processor flags, but -f (e.g. -ffast-math) is not.

Comment: @user502515 Yup, knew that one. Is that relevant to my answer, though?

Comment: @Adrian Petrescu: These days, automake does have Vala support: http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Vala-Support.html